# contact.php not validating or sending correctly after adding new input fields

Tags: php, validation

php novice back again with some minor issues, I've researched for hours but can't find the solution.

I already use this form for another form and it works fine, but this time I added the Input fields of nric, rate and a checkbox "agree". These are the 3 fields that don't validate and stop the form from sending. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code:

```
//Retrieve form data. 
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead
$name = ($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];
$phone = ($_GET['phone']) ? $_GET['phone'] : $_POST['phone'];
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];
$nric = ($_GET['nric']) ?$_GET['nric'] : $_POST['nric'];
$rate = ($_GET['rate']) ?$_GET['rate'] : $_POST['rate'];
$comment = ($_GET['comment']) ?$_GET['comment'] : $_POST['comment'];
$agree = ($_GET['agree']) ?$_GET['agree'] : $_POST['agree'];


//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1

if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Simple server side validation for POST data, of course, you should validate the email
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your Full name Surname in UPPERCASE.';
if (!$phone) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your contact number - e.g. +6012345678.';
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your email.';
if (!$nric) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter your Business No or NRIC if not a business.'; 
if (!$rate) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please enter the rate you wish to pay (in RM)'; 
if (!$comment) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please describe what you require this person for and when.'; 
if (!$agree) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please agree to the Booking Fee.';

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail
if (!$errors) {

        //recipient - replace your email here
        $to = 'me@myemail.com'; 
        //sender - from the form
        $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

        //subject and the html message
        $subject = 'Message from ' . $name; 
        $message = 'Name: ' . $name . '<br/><br/>
                             Phone: ' . $phone . '<br/><br/>
                             Email: ' . $email . '<br/><br/>
                             NRIC: ' . $nric . '<br/><br/>
                             Rate: ' . $rate . '<br/><br/>
                             Agree: ' . $agree . '<br/><br/>
                             Message: ' . nl2br($comment) . '<br/>';

//send the mail
$result = sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from);

//if POST was used, display the message straight away
if ($_POST) {
    if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.';
    else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

//else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that 
//ajax script can react accordingly
//1 means success, 0 means failed
} else {
    echo $result;   
}

    //if the errors array has values
    } else {
        //display the errors message
        for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br/>';
        echo '<a href="index.html">Back</a>';
        exit;
    }


    //Simple mail function with HTML header
    function sendmail($to, $subject, $message, $from) {
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

        $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

        if ($result) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't as simple as a missing quote.

Look at

```
$to = me@myemail.com';
```

It should be

```
$to = 'me@myemail.com'; // ** Missing leading quote on string
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo when I removed the real address... still does not work.

Comment: Have you performed a var_dump() on your $_GET when you are using that and your $_POST when you are using that, in fact just dump both and be done with it... Do they contain the results your code is expecting?

Comment: I found the reason why my form was not validating.... DUH!!! there is also a js file I needed to update. But now I'm faced with another issue... how do I get the checkbox to validate?
Do I use  var agree = $('input[name=agree]');
or  var agree = $('checkbox[name=agree]');
Neither seem to work